# Computing $\iint_S\frac{x(x^2+y)}{y^3\ln(x)}dxdy,$ where $S=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2| e\le x\le e^2,\frac{x^2}{\ln(x)}\le y\le x^2\right\}.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Using a suitable substitution of variables ($u=\ln(x),v=\ldots,$ ), compute the integral $$\iint_S\frac{x(x^2+y)}{y^3\ln(x)}dxdy,$$ where $$S=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid  e\le x\le e^2,\frac{x^2}{\ln(x)}\le y\le x^2\right\}.$$

**My attempt:**

I thought of applying the following corollary:

> Let $\varphi,\psi:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous functions s. t. $\varphi(x)\le\psi(x),\forall x\in[a,b].$ Let $C$ be the part of the $xy$ plane in the stripe $a\le x\le b$ between the graphs of the functions $\varphi$ and $\psi;$ i. e.,  $(x,y)\in C\iff a\le x\le b,\varphi(x)\le y\le\psi(x).$ Let $f:C\to\Bbb R$ be an integrable function. Then $$\iint_C f=\int_a^b\left(\int_{\varphi(x)}^{\psi(x)}f(x,y)dy\right)dx.$$

1. $1\le\ln_{\mid [e,e^2]}\le 2\implies\frac12\le\frac1{\ln(x)}\le 1,\forall x\in[e,e^2]$
2. Let's define $\varphi,\psi:[e,e^2]\to\Bbb R,\varphi(x)=\frac{x^2}{\ln(x)},\psi(x)=x^2.$ Then, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are continuous functions and $\varphi(x)\le\psi(x),\forall x\in[e,e^2].$

Now, I applied the corollary to the set $C:=S$ and the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x(x^2+y)}{y^3\ln(x)}:$

$$\begin{aligned}\iint_S\frac{x(x^2+y)}{y^3\ln(x)}dxdy&\\&=\int_e^{e^2}\int_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}\frac{x(x^2+y)}{y^3\ln(x)}dydx\\&=\int_e^{e^2}\int_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}\left(\frac{x^3}{\ln(x)}\frac1{y^3}+\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\frac1{y^2}\right)dydx\\&=\int_e^{e^2}\frac{x^3}{\ln(x)}\int_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}\frac{dy}{y^3}dx+\int_e^{e^2}\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\int_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}\frac{dy}{y^2}dx\\&=\int_e^{e^2}-\frac{x^3}{\ln(x)}\frac1{2y^2}\Big|_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}dx+\int_e^{e^2}-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\frac1y\Big|_{x^2/\ln(x)}^{x^2}dx\\&=-\int_e^{e^2}\left(\frac{x^3}{\ln(x)}\left(\frac1{2x^4}-\frac{\ln(x)^2}{2x^4}-\right)+\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\left(\frac1{x^2}-\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}\right)\right)dx\\&=-\int_e^{e^2}\left(\frac1{2x\ln(x)}-\frac{\ln(x)}{2x}+\frac1{x\ln(x)}-\frac1x\right)dx\\&=\int_e^{e^2}\left(\frac3{2\ln(x)}\frac1x-\frac{\ln(x)}2\frac1x-\frac1x\right)dx\\&=\begin{bmatrix}u=\ln(x)\\du=\frac{dx}{x}\end{bmatrix}\\&=-\int_1^{2}\left(\frac3{2u}-\frac{u}2-1\right)du\\&=-\left(\frac32\ln(u)-\frac{u^2}4-u\right)\Big|_1^2\\&=-\left(\frac32\ln(\ln(x))-\frac{\ln(x)^2}4-\ln(x)\right)\Big|_e^{e^2}\\&=-\left(\frac32\ln(2)-1-2+\frac14+1\right)\\&=-\frac32\ln(2)+\frac74\end{aligned}$$

**Update:** Mistake corrected

**Question:**

Is it correct and is there a better way? I feel as if the hint in the parentheses is to apply the theorem about the change of variables, but I couldn't think of a suitable transformation $\varphi: C\subseteq\Bbb R^2\to\ S$ so that $\varphi^{-1}(x,y)=(u,v).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the calculation a bit simpler with a change of variables. For instance, if you define $ x = e^u, y=e^{2u} v$, the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_1^2 \int_{1/u}^1 \dfrac{1+v}{u v^3} dv du=& \int_1^2\frac{1}{u}\int_{1/u}^1 (v^{-3}+v^{-2})dv\, du=\int_1^2\left( \frac{-3/2}{u}+\frac{u^2}{2}+u\right) du\\
 = & \frac 14(7 - 6 \log 2)
\end{align*}.

Comment: @Winter That's not how it works... The integration is in $u$ and so are the integration limits, it is irrelevant what is its value in terms of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I unnecessarily returned the final integration back to $x$ and the bounds for $x,$ when I got to the primitive function already, but I also made two mistakes, one probably because of that redundant return and one with the - sign.